# Repair a Corrupted SD Card?

Tags: pi-2, sd-card, image

My Raspberry Pi SD card has gotten corrupted (possibly from accidently running a high amp current through the Pi) and I would like to recover some of the files.

I have tried using several ext4 format readers such as Paragon, and they haven't worked. I've tried to run a live Linux enviroment, but the corrupted SD card makes mounting it impossible.

I took a .ISO disk image copy of the SD card, divided into partitions, and converted that disk image into a text file, which I can view using the built in `emacs` software. Here, I can clearly see the corrupted sections of the SD card. For example: [image]

The red number codes (I believe) are the corrupted parts - there is much more than this.

My question is: Is it possible that there is a pattern to the numbers that appear in corrupted places? In other words, can I "decode" the corruption and repair the corrupted sections using a custom program (Or is there already one in existence)?

Comment: You should run `e2fsck` on the ext4 partition.

Answer (score 4):

What you see is *not* evidence of a corrupt SD card, but rather artefacts of a program not being able to display your encoding. Try opening the file in another editor, alternatively have a look at [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/549497/how-to-switch-back-text-encoding-to-utf-8-with-emacs#549507) for a discussion around encodings in emacs.

Comment: This is certainly correct WRT the example text.  It's UTF-8 encoded; those will be two byte characters, e.g., `\304\215` is č, `\303\255` is í.  http://www.utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?number=512&utf8=oct  Quick google: "číslo" is Czech for "number".